# Parse.com - cannot add specific user to role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I cant seem to query a specific user and add him to a role on Parse.com using the JS API. What did I do wrong?

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "testParent");  
query.find({
success: function(person) {
// Do stuff

var roleACL = new Parse.ACL();
var role = new Parse.Role("Parent", roleACL);
role.getUsers().add(person[0]);
role.save();


}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to add any user to a role, given a role name:

```
function addUserToRoleNamed(user, roleName) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.equalTo("name", roleName);
    return query.first().then(function(role) {
        var relation = role.relation("users");
        relation.add(user);
        return role.save();
    });
}
```

Here's how to get a user and call that function:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "testParent");  
return query.first().then(function(user) {
    return addUserToRoleNamed(user, "Parent");
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(result));
}, function(error) {
    console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in my answer:  there's a chance the user running this code is not entitled to create roles, there's also a chance that setting an empty ACL is not valid.  But even if the OP code did work, it wouldn't work as you wish, because it wouldn't add the user to the role, it would replace the role with a new role that would always have just one user -- the last user added -- in it.  I would create roles manually and use something like the code I suggest to add to them.

Comment: Btw I got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` for the `return query.first().then(function(user) {`...

Comment: That snippet presumed it was placed inside a function. Was it?

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I'm scratching my head on this one. I can create roles, but can't add to an existing role, even when using the master key or when it is readable/writeable to the public.

Comment: @kokernutz did you resolve this problem? I'm having the same issue now. It times out with 504.

Comment: @vburojevic - I no longer have any parse projects in production, but this continues to run in a dev environment.  Maybe I can help if you share some debug info, like error messages.

Comment: @vburojevic i stopped working on the project, sorry!